# PhP Exec GIT command from crontab

Tags: php, git, deployment, exec, cron

I have a deploy script which i have to execute every time i change my config files. Which is a bummer. 
I tried to add the deploy script to my crontab, but from the logs i see that this command is failing in crontab because you are tehnically not in a git repo

> exec('git log -1 --format="%H"')

This fella should deliver a revision number so the code can use it, but it dous not execute when you run the script from crontab.

Anyone has any idea how to make it work?

Comment: exec('cd /your/git/repo && "git log -1 --format="%H"'); ???

Comment: Will try it. Will give feedback as soon i get it.